# how do I get multiple coordinates for multi touch from a UIGesture

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I have three gestures: 2-finger tap, 3-finger tap, and 4-finger tap. I need to get coordinates accordingly.

I have tried the following to get the coordinated of 2 fingers tap but app keeps crashing:

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

NSArray *twoTouch = [touches allObjects];
UITouch *tOne = [twoTouch objectAtIndex:0];
UITouch *tTwo = [twoTouch objectAtIndex:1];
CGPoint firstTouch = [tOne locationInView:[tOne view]];
CGPoint secondTouch = [tTwo locationInView:[tTwo view]];

NSLog(@"point one: %@", firstTouch);
NSLog(@"point two: %@", secondTouch);


[twoTouch release];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your application is not checking if there actually **are** two touches.
If you tap the screen with one finger you will get one touch in the "touches".

Try something like this.

```
if(touches.count > 1 && touches.count < 3)
{
    // Your code for two touches.
}
```

Otherwise, the part where your program crashes is the [twoTouch objectAtIndex:1] because objectAtIndex:1 doesn't exist.

(I know this is a really old question but I answered it anyways.)